# Multiple field values from a row in same column of a JQUERY datatable using Ajax

Tags: jquery, datatables

I only having experienced with HTML table datasource method for JQUERY Datatable. So am doing it simply by

```
$("#mytable").datatable();
```

But now I've a table with more than 10000 rows. So when applying the plugin to that table, initially the table with 10000 rows shows first and after the plugin being applied pagination occurs and only 10 rows shows first. But before that every rows are showing which makes the page very tall and it takes sometime in mobile browsers to apply the plugin. So till it finishes users can view all rows.. That causes some troubles.. So I thought about AJAX way for datasource and I've fetched the JSON object from server side. But my table should be like there will be an HTML formatting in each cells or each cells has to include multiple values from the same row in a different layout.

[image]

As you can see the first column having a checkbox.. Second column cell having an HTML structure in which name on the first line and ID in second line and also date is on the same box right alligned by **float:right to that span** which is having few spans and some other tags. Same way third column too.. So how can I achieve this to show multiple values in the same column and must follow the HTML layout I have now.

Answer (score 1):

If a shift to AJAX is too drastic, and your main concern is the initial height of the DOM `<table>`, you can always hide the table and show the dataTable when it is instantiated. By that the `<table>` will only take space up when it has become a dataTable.

```css
#example {
    display: none;
}
```

```js
$("#example").dataTable().show();
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/tyevzmjz/**

Comment: Thats something I can try since the table is too drastic as you said to handle with ajax.. But I would like to show some "busy" image over that area when the table is hidden. Thanks for that..

Answer (score 0):

I think that using ajax to load your table will be the best scenario, you can control the returned result as you put the the structure of returned json, you can also make checkbox column using this snippet:

```
"sName": "FieldName", "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                    if (data === "True") {
                        return '<input type=\"checkbox\" checked value="' + data + '">';
                    } else {
                        return '<input type=\"checkbox\" value="' + data + '">';
                    }
                }
```

where data is the value returned from your json